# ComboBox hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I have a problem in populating or regarding the response of my javascript.

I have two different  which is  and . The div#individual represents the first form that has a a div#address. And I have my second div which is the div#group. My problem is when i choose the "individual" in the subtype combobox the div#address works perfectly but when it comes to the "group" in the subtype combobox it doesn't respond like the first one. I set the div#address with the same class. Didn't work.

How ca I solved this?

Note: Im just using .hide() and .show() for both div#individual and div#group. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the inputs of address for individual and  the inputs of address for group should use different id and name.

Comment: not working. What happened is whatever i set to the "Town or city" of th div#individual combobox is the one being recall or set in the div#group.

Comment: since they're using same class and same id.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is useful for u please try it?

```
<script id="main" type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    var val=$("#selectid option:selected").text();
      if(val == "Internet")
      {
        $("#new1").show();
        $("#new2").hide();

      }
      else if(val == "Media")
      {
        $("#new1").hide(); 
        $("#new2").show();

      }    
    $('#selectid').change(function()
    {      
    var val=$(this).val();

        $("#internet").val('');
        $("#media").val('');

      if(val == "Internet")
      {
        $("#new1").show();
        $("#new2").hide();
      }
      if(val == "Media")
      {
        $("#new1").show();
        $("#new2").hide();
      }
    val = "";

    });
    });
    </script>
```